# why would same branch in git need to merge?

Tags: git, merge

Here it is my problem:
   I use SourceTree to manager my work,while my colleague use Tortoisegit.

but we are in the same branch -- master,and I notice that the graph has many branchs:(the repository has only a master),why？there is not other branch..

[image]

and they sometimes commit a merge:

[image]

It confuses me,i throught merge in git is happened between two branchs,and i did review the documentation of merge:https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging.

Comment: Every person using Git has their own copy of the repository, and those count as different branches when you merge them. (Also, branches as in diverging paths of history aren’t branches in the Git sense of “names that point to commits”.)

Comment: Every time you pull, there is a merge done if you have local commits in your branch. Prefer a rebase workflow with`git pull --rebase`